# Windows batch command: multiple folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

Following Windows batch command converts all tif images in the folder C:\RootFolder\Folder1.

```
for %%i in (C:\RootFolder\Folder1\*.tif) do "Tiff2Pdf.exe" -o C:\RootFolder\Folder1\%%~ni.pdf %%i
```

How can I do it for all the folders available in RootFolder?

```
RootFolder
  -Folder1
  -Folder2
  -Folder3
   .
   .
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /s C:\RootFolder\Folder1\*.tif') DO "Tiff2Pdf.exe" -o "%%~dpi%%~ni.pdf" "%%i"
```

- Use `dir /s /b` to do a full recursive enumeration
- Use `FOR /F "delims="` to parse the results and handle paths with spaces.
- Use the %%~dpi%% to get the directory of each file.
- Use %%~ni to get the file's name with out an extension.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but only when "delim=" is removed.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed a typo. It should be `"delims="` not `"delim="`

Answer (score 1):

There's another way - just to add it:

```
@echo off
for /r "c:\rootfolder\folder1" %%a in (*.tif) do "Tiff2Pdf.exe" -o "%%~dpna.pdf" "%%a"
```

I also changed the loop variable to `a` because i is close to l and I and 1 in many fonts.